# Simperium and MagicalRecord

Tags: core-data, magicalrecord, simperium

I've been using Simperium with [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) which among other things, automatically sets up the core data stack. The latest Simperium has a new setup in which the persistentstorecoordinator for the managedobjectcontext passed in the startup must be nil or it crashes. Any workarounds to this while still using both Simperium and MagicalRecord? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried to resolve it. When using the previous version of simperium, then they both worked together. But there were several occasions of lost relationship when syncing. So now I removed magical records and use simperium without. There were no more data corruption issues.
So it might be best not to use both together.